# How does one know when try fails?

Tags: ocaml

```
let z = 4 in let y=5 in
try
  y = z+x
  with Failure msg -> msg = "Free identifier: x"
```

If we do this, how does OCaml know if try fails?? In real, I'm trying to "try function with fail msg" but my function has to return int value. How can you make OCaml know that try has failed by returning int value?
My real code is something like this:

```
try
  let ast =  (Prog ([], (Add (Id "x", Num 1)))) in
  interp ast = NumV 5 
  with Failure msg -> msg = "Free identifier: x"
```

but function has to return int (NumV is NumV of int) and this code doesn't work. msg doesn't show at fail and it does fails.

```
let interp (p: Ast.prog) : int = ~
```

I added function interp for additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function truly has to return an int value, then you have to pick an int value to represent failure. Let's say you pick `-1` as your special failure value. Then the code might look like this:

```
let f x = try x + 1 with Failure _ -> -1
```

You can't return a message in the failure case and an int in the usual case. All the returns of a function have to be the same type.

That's why there is a type named `result`. It's used to combine a failure type and a success type into one larger type. The failure value is constructed by `Error <value>` and the success value is constructed by `Ok <value>`. These values can be two different types because the `Error` and the `Ok` are used to tell which is which. This code would look like this:

```
let f x = try Ok (x + 1) with Failure _ -> Error "msg"
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is exit the program with a custom error message, you need to exit the program after printing your error message:

```ml
try
  let ast =  (Prog ([], (Add (Id "x", Num 1)))) in
  interp ast = NumV 5 
with Failure msg ->
  Format.eprintf "Free identifier: x";
  exit 2
```

You might also be trying to raise a custom exception:

```ml
exception My_exception of string
try
  let ast =  (Prog ([], (Add (Id "x", Num 1)))) in
  interp ast = NumV 5 
with Failure msg ->
  raise (My_exception "Free identifier: x")
```

If the inner equality is supposed to be a pattern matching, you might be trying to write

```ml
let ast =  (Prog ([], (Add (Id "x", Num 1)))) in
match interp ast with
| NumV n -> n
| _ ->
  Format.eprintf "Free identifier: x";
  exit 2
```

(you could also raise an exception, it is unclear what to do without more context)

Answer (score -1):

A value Ok x means that the computation succeeded with x, and a value Error e means that it failed.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is this value Error e?

Comment: Exceptions are not handled with the `'a result` type, these are two different things.